# How to get properties from FieldInfo in C#?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, reflection

I have this method and want to get all properties from the FieldInfos? How to get it?

```
  private static void FindFields(ICollection<FieldInfo> fields, Type t)
  {
     var flags = BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.DeclaredOnly;

     foreach (var field in t.GetFields(flags))
     {
        fields.Add(field);
     }

     var baseType = t.BaseType;
     if (baseType != null)
     {
        FindFields(fields, baseType);
     }
  }

     var fields = new Collection<FieldInfo>();
     FindFields(fields, this.GetType());
```

Thanks.

Best regards.

Comment: Maybe you're confusing properties and fields. Do you want the `PropertyInfo`s of the properties that are backed the the fields you are collecting in your method, or do you want to values of all those fields?

Comment: I want the values of all those fields like .Text, .Name, .Size etc...

Comment: Do you want to use reflection to get all the fields, and then use reflection to get all the properties on each FieldInfo and display the value? It seems that as Martinho says you may be confusing properties with fields.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To get the value of a field for a specific object use `GetValue` and pass the object for which you want to get the value.

```
var fields = new Collection<FieldInfo>();
FindFields(fields, this.GetType()); 

foreach (var field in fields)
{
    Console.WriteLine( "{0} = {1}", field.Name , field.GetValue(this));
}
```